# Exception when using Mockito with Java11

Tags: java, mockito, java-11, powermockito, byte-buddy

We're upgrading from Java 8 to 11. After having done all the necessary SDK changes, I started running our unit tests using maven. All tests that use `Mockito` fail with

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
class org.mockito.codegenEventapiManager$MockitoMock$1091821173 cannot be cast to class
org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockAccess
(org.mockito.codegenEventapiManager$MockitoMock$1091821173 is in unnamed module of loader
org.powermock.core.classloader.javassist.JavassistMockClassLoader @1473b8c0;
org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockAccess is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:48)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:41)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1896)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1805)
    [...line where we cal Mockito, rest is ommitted]
```

Could this be related to a version number mismatch in some of the dependencies?

We're using

```
mockito-core 2.24.0, excluding byte-buddy, byte-buddy-agent and objenesis
powermock-module-testng 2.0.4 (excluding above)
powermock-api-mockito2 2.0.4
objenesis 3.1
byte-buddy 1.9.7
byte-buddy-agent 1.9.7
```

Mocking the class is straight forward:

```
EventapiManager mockManager = Mockito.mock(EventapiManager.class);
```

The mocked class itself is public and everything is working fine on Java 8.

Comment: Just try using the latest version of byte-buddy `<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.7</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Tried, but I get the same result, unfortunately. I tried the latest version of `mockito-core` as well, no difference. I tried excluding `mockito-core` entirely and use the built-in version from PowerMock, the path is slightly different but the result is the same.

Comment: Probably a problem with PowerMock. I'd suggest to ask on their issue tracker.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved my issue in an unexpected way: while googling for solutions I came across [this](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/864#issuecomment-494686382) comment, which describes another failing test that I had. In that test fixture, we indeed use the `PowerMock` annotation described in the comment, but had none of the ignored packages suggested there. So I added them, making the complete list of ignored packages:

```java
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.script.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.*"})
```

This has mysteriously resolved ALL failures, including the above that had its fixture in a different package.

Comment: Thanks, this strangely enough worked for me as well when I used the same ignore list across all of my test classes.